# FusionTables layer above polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

On my website: http://mapa.polskieszlaki.pl/ I'm using FusionTables for displaying markers (over 5000 of them). I've got also GroundLayer with regions (pink ones). But I wanted to change them to polygon (less loading) and have one problem.
FusionTable layer is below polygon and I want it to be above (markers are most important).
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the polygon in a FusionTableLayer, load that first, then load the FusionTablesLayer with the markers.

Comment: It works, but sadly You can use styles for first FusionLayer only and You have to use default red color. Hope Google will expand it.

Comment: You can use the FusionTables UI to style the markers.  It is only javascript ("dynamic") styling that is only allowed on a single layer.